# Trouble setting margins with Resumé header

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, positioning, margins, fancyhdr

I am trying to typeset my resumé in LaTeX and have created a header that I am really happy with. However, now that I am starting to fill in the rest of my information the margins I have set up to place my header in the correct place are messing with the text.

I was wondering if there is a better way to format my header so that I don't have to mess with my margins so much. When I try to add text, it either comes out so that the left side is off of the page or when I use `\flushleft` the text is placed near the center of the page.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx, wrapfig,anyfontsize, color, amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\topmargin = -45pt
\hoffset= -70pt
\voffset=-15pt
\textwidth = 550pt
\textheight = 685pt
\headheight = 0pt
\headsep = 0pt
\oddsidemargin = -20pt


\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{i}{0.15\textwidth}
\begin{picture}(90,70)
\hspace{20mm}
\includegraphics[clip=true, trim=0 75 76 0, scale = .7]{FHS_Ship_Wheel.jpg}
\linethickness{0.75mm}
\put(0,0){\line(0,1){65}}
\put(0,0){\line(-1,0){65}}
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){450}}
\end{picture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent
\\
\\
\vspace{-11.5mm}
\hspace{115mm}
%Upper right-hand Corner
\begin{tabular} {lc}
\text{Address Line 1} & \textcolor{Gray}{ Address}\\
\text{Address Line 2 }& \textcolor{Gray}{}\\
\href{thisisnotmyemail@gmail.com}{Email Address} & \textcolor{Gray}{ Email}\\
$\left(555\right)555 -5555$ & \textcolor{Gray}{ Cell} \\
\end{tabular}
\\
\vspace{-8mm}
{\fontsize{45}{5.4}
\selectfont 
\hspace{2mm} John Q. Public}

\end{document}
```

Because I am not able to post the image I am using, it can be found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:FHS_Ship_Wheel.jpg

Some possible ideas I had were to either wrap all of the header into one figure or image so I could just place it at the top or use a package to format headers that would allow me to lay it out with the title next to the image as I have done. Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve but hoffset and oddsidemargin total -90pt so given the 1in reference  you are specifying that text lines start around 18pt to the left _off_ the page edge. `article` does not have a `9pt` option so that is doing nothing other than generating a warning. I'd suggest you delete all the length settings in the preamble and specify page layout using the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `wrapfig` for this. Just build a sequence of boxes. For the margins I used 1cm at all sides, adjust to suit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx,anyfontsize, color, amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{picture}(65,65)
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[clip, trim=0 75 76 0,width=65pt]{FHS_Ship_Wheel.jpg}}
\linethickness{0.75mm}
\put(65,0){\line(0,1){65}}
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){65}}
\end{picture}\hfill
{\fontsize{45}{0}\selectfont John Q. Public}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}lc@{}}
\text{Address Line 1} & \textcolor{Gray}{ Address}\\
\text{Address Line 2 }& \textcolor{Gray}{}\\
\href{thisisnotmyemail@gmail.com}{Email Address} & \textcolor{Gray}{Email}\\
(555)\,555-5555 & \textcolor{Gray}{Cell} \\
\end{tabular}\par
\smallskip
\hrule height .375mm depth .375mm

\end{document}
```

The thin lines are drawn by the `showframe` option, that you'll remove after using it for fine tuning the page parameters.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks really nice. I like the way the title looks when the `\hrule` is underlining the image and the name is much closer to the image as well. So I got rid of the `\hfill`after the picture and pushed it down a bit. Thanks again.